# In CakePHP, how do I force an update for another user's session after their data is modified?

Tags: session, cakephp

If I change another user's data, their session will hold their old data until they logout.  In cases where I am, for example, changing their `status` to ban the user, this is not ideal.

Thus far, I have thought of two solutions:

1. Create a user-expiration value in the session, forcing an update from the database once that time has passed.  Downside: not anywhere near instant, tons of unnecessary database calls, and seems awkward.
2. Use databases to manage sessions, somehow link the user's session to their `user_id`, and 'flag' the sessions for an update.  Downside: forces me to use database session management, requires an update on all matching user sessions (which could be a lot, depending on how users use the website), seems awkward as well.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you asking this because after saving User data it shows the user data the same so you have to log in and log out to see if User data has been modified?

Comment: Not specifically for the current user... that's a much simpler fix.  I'm talking about when I use admin privilege to modify another account.  In the example of their `status`, if I modify them to no longer be an active user (say, I change it to a banned status), they will still be able to continue on using the site until they specifically log out.  In the case of `status`, this is particularly not ideal, but even in other cases this could cause some grief.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sessions in the database (and include the `user_id`) and you would query the `users` table on each page load, to see if the user exists/is active.

Comment: I was with you up to `user_id` (sounds like my second solution)... then I lost you.  Could you elaborate a bit... I'm not sure I understand your method?

Comment: when a particular session is used by an user, you can also check if the user is still active

Comment: Okay; perhaps I'm totally misunderstanding... but wouldn't that be the same thing as simply updating the session from the database at each page load?